# Is there any selectivity between the C-2 and C-4 positions of pyridine in SNAr reactions?

Tags: organic-chemistry, heterocyclic-compounds, regioselectivity

In nucleophilic aromatic substitution (S<sub>N</sub>Ar) reactions on pyridines, displacement of leaving groups at C-2 and C-4 is favoured because [the negative charge in the intermediate can be delocalised onto the nitrogen atom](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/103097/16683).

However, is there any intrinsic difference in the rates of substitution at C-2 and C-4 (assuming the leaving groups at both positions are the same)? If so, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

True, the *para* (C4) and *ortho* (C2) positions give similar resonance structures but consider the fact that:

1. For an $\ce{S_{N}Ar}$ reaction the electron rich nucleophile must attack. Nitrogen, being highly electronegative, does draw electrons away from the *ortho* and *para* positions but because the electron clouds would be larger around nitrogen, it is harder for the nucleophile to approach the *ortho* than the *para*. You could think of it as the lone pair on Nitrogen being a steric shield of some sort.
2. An attack on the *para* position gives a symmetric intermediate. This would be lower in energy compared to the intermediate produced by an attack on the *ortho* position.

As such, the *para* product would be the kinetic product of the reaction whereas the *ortho* product would be the thermodynamic product. Statistically *ortho* should be attacked more often as well, as there are two positions whereas there is only one *para* position.

Comment: I really don't think it's that simple. If you look in the literature (pyridine SNAr is very common in med chem for example), there are examples of both selective C-2 and selective C-4 substitution, and I think it really depends on conditions and exact substrate. See e.g. [Baran group meeting](https://www.scripps.edu/baran/images/grpmtgpdf/Gutekunst_Apr_10.pdf) *"Pyridines readily undergo SNAr, usually faster at C-4 than C-2/6, but highly dependent on nucleophile and conditions"*