# Nucleophilic aromatic substitution on pyrimidines: C2 vs C4 selectivity

Tags: organic-chemistry, heterocyclic-compounds, regioselectivity

[There are many similar questions on Chemistry.SE (e.g. [1](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/51946), [2](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/77423)) and a quick search will reveal all of them, but nothing on this in particular.]

The reaction of 2,4-halopyrimidines with nucleophiles generally leads to selective displacement of the halide at the 4-position:<sup>1</sup>

[image: SNAr on 2,4-dichloropyrimidine]

In their textbook, Joule and Mills don't explain why, though, simply saying that it "is the normal situation for nucleophilic – 4-chloro > 2-chloro".

I don't see any obvious difference in the stability of the anionic intermediates, either (the so-called Meisenheimer complexes).

What can explain the regioselectivity of the above reaction?

---

*Reference*

1. Joule, J. A.; Mills, K. *Heterocyclic Chemistry,* 5th ed.; Wiley: Chichester, U.K., 2010, p 257.

Comment: This is a simple enough system that it might be amenable to computation...

Comment: It's maybe not as obvious as you might think, @Zhe. If you go via just the electron density (or even just the NMR shifts/how deshielded) it kinda looks like it *should* go the other way round.

Comment: My question is linked anyways. I've also synthesized and calculated 2- and 4pyrimidyl compounds and in ym case the 4-pyrimidyl residue is more electron withdrawing than the 2.

Comment: @notevans I specifically chose not to make assumptions about electronics or orbital overlap factors. If the computed preference agrees with experiment, you can then proceed to rationalize based on the results.

Comment: What kinda mechanism does this reaction undergo ?

Answer (score 1):

An explanation can be provided by frontier molecular orbital theory.  The LUMO coefficient is higher on the C4 vs C2.  This is a general effect meaning that an EWG para to the leaving group is more reactive than ortho.  See 4-halopyridines vs 2-halo and 4-nitrobenznes vs 2-nitro.  There could also be an effect from the repulsion between the nitrogen lone pairs and the approaching electron rich nucleophile, which would be greater in proximity to 2 nitrogens rather than 1.

Answer (score -4):

Try drawing the resonance hybrides out. You'll soon realise that the intermediate formed when substitution accours at the c4 position can be stabilised by three resonance hybrids!

:)

Comment: Unless I’m gravely mistaken, the same can be said of the intermediate for C2 substitution.